# Delete button not working on forum comment

Tags: 7, ajax

I am using the [AJAX Comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) module.
For forum I am using the Advance Forum module.
In forum topic  I have some post replies, my issue is when I am click on delete button on forum comment a popup is shown with message:

> You are not authorised to access this page

I have assigned the permission so any one can delete their own comment.

I don't know what is the issue because on other content type comment its working fine but only on forum comment its not working.

Comment: Works fine for me on clean drupal install with the core Forum module, with Advanced Forum, AJAX comments didn't work for me.

Comment: Hi,Sssweat same issue i forgot to mention I am also using advance forum.
and with advance forum AJAX comment not work fine only on delete condation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug report](https://www.drupal.org/node/2459001) about this

According to [one of the comments](https://www.drupal.org/node/2459001#comment-10812354) written by Ravathi.M

> i am also having the same issue the comment wraper class is
>   missing.for the initial execution.then i have added the
>   ajax-comment-wraper class by custom js code.now it is working fine

Looks like the solution is that you need to add the `ajax-comment-wraper comment-wrapper-[post#]` class name to your forum comments.

Go to `/sites/all/modules/advanced_forum/styles/naked` folder and replace the **advanced-forum-naked-post.tpl.php** with this code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Theme implementation: Template for each forum post whether node or comment.
 *
 * All variables available in node.tpl.php and comment.tpl.php for your theme
 * are available here. In addition, Advanced Forum makes available the following
 * variables:
 *
 * - $top_post: TRUE if we are formatting the main post (ie, not a comment)
 * - $reply_link: Text link / button to reply to topic.
 * - $total_posts: Number of posts in topic (not counting first post).
 * - $new_posts: Number of new posts in topic, and link to first new.
 * - $links_array: Unformatted array of links.
 * - $account: User object of the post author.
 * - $name: User name of post author.
 * - $author_pane: Entire contents of the Author Pane template.
 */
?>

<?php if ($top_post): ?>
  <?php print $topic_header ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<div id="<?php print $post_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> ajax-comment-wrapper comment-wrapper-<?php print str_replace('post-','',$post_id); ?>" <?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <div class="forum-post-info clearfix">
    <div class="forum-posted-on">
      <?php print $date ?>

      <?php
      // This whole section is for printing the "new" marker. With core comment
      // we just need to check a variable. With Node Comment, we need to do
      // extra work to keep the views caching used for Node Comment from
      // caching the new markers.
      ?>
      <?php if (!$top_post): ?>
        <?php if (!empty($new)): ?>
          <a id="new"><span class="new">(<?php print $new ?>)</span></a>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if (!empty($first_new)): ?>
          <?php print $first_new; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if (!empty($new_output)): ?>
          <?php print $new_output; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php /* End of posted on div. */ ?>

    <?php if (!empty($in_reply_to)): ?>
     <span class="forum-in-reply-to"><?php print $in_reply_to; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php /* Add a note when a post is unpublished so it doesn't rely on theming. */ ?>
    <?php if (!$node->status): ?>
      <span class="unpublished-post-note"><?php print t("Unpublished post") ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <span class="forum-post-number"><?php print $permalink; ?></span>
  </div> <?php /* End of post info div. */ ?>

  <div class="forum-post-wrapper">
    <div class="forum-post-panel-sub">
      <?php if (!empty($author_pane)): ?>
        <?php print $author_pane; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="forum-post-panel-main clearfix">
      <?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
        <div class="forum-post-title">
          <?php print $title ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <div class="forum-post-content">
        <?php
          // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
          // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
          hide($content['taxonomy_forums']);
          hide($content['comments']);
          hide($content['links']);
          if (!$top_post)
            hide($content['body']);
          print render($content);
          // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
        ?>
      </div>

      <?php if (!empty($post_edited)): ?>
        <div class="post-edited">
          <?php print $post_edited ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if (!empty($signature)): ?>
        <div class="author-signature">
          <?php print $signature ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php /* End of post wrapper div. */ ?>

  <div class="forum-post-footer clearfix">
    <div class="forum-jump-links">
      <a href="#forum-topic-top" title="<?php print t('Jump to top of page'); ?>" class="af-button-small"><span><?php print t("Top"); ?></span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="forum-post-links">
      <?php print render($content['links']); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php /* End of footer div. */ ?>
</div>
<?php /* End of main wrapping div. */ ?>
<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
```

Since the forum post and the 1st comment have the same number `1` you will notice that clicking <kbd>reply</kbd> will affect the node post as well. Therefore, you will need to use jQuery to modify or remove the `1` from `comment-wrapper-1` of the forum (node) post.

Comment: Which Place i am add above class

Comment: idk, check one of your content type comments, right click and inspect element with your browser and see where that class goes.

Comment: I know but in which file i write the code or give me the example of code

Comment: @AnkitGupta it's hard to do when idk where it's suppose to go. The advanced forum module comes with a lot of template files, it probably goes inside one of them. Else, you could use custom jQuery code to insert it. Sorry, I don't have time to setup a D7 server to check this out, I hope you can figure this part out.

Comment: Thanks Sssweat for help
I will try to find the place where i am written that code

Comment: @AnkitGupta how did it go? where you able to figure it out?

Comment: Hi Sssweat,

No i can not able to figure out that file or place
I am till working on it

Comment: @AnkitGupta I'll take a look.

Comment: @AnkitGupta updated my answer.